# Trying to make a shader that draws pixels

Tags: shader, game-maker-studio-2

I'm trying to make a shader that draws pixels at positions that are defined in an array (I don't really know how to describe it well but its basically an array that has a value for every pixel on the screen, like 1 if its gonna be a pixel at the position and 0 if not), but I don't know how to actually make it (mainly because I don't know much about shaders).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have data for every pixel, you would want [buffer_set_surface](https://manual.yoyogames.com/#t=GameMaker_Language%2FGML_Reference%2FBuffers%2Fbuffer_set_surface.htm), not a shader.

Furthermore, if you want to pass in a large number of colors into a shader, the input would usually be a texture (`sampler2D`) rather than an array - there are limits to how much data you can pass in via a uniform and shaders cannot accept variable-sized arrays.

For learning shaders in general, you can start with [this tutorial](https://xorshaders.weebly.com/tutorials/shader-basics1).